# SelectInput in react-admin only shows last 20 items of list from resource

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I have this code in a creation dialog

```
<ReferenceInput source="id_activofijo" reference="activos/activosfijos" >
  <SelectInput  label="Activo" optionText="Descripcion"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

`activos/activosfijos` resource has almost 100 items. `SelectInput` only shows last 25 items of list. I guess it has some kind of max-items=25 in some html or css property set by default.
Does anyone knows how to bypass that default limit? I couldn't find any clue in react-admin's nor MUI's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you need are in the [ReferenceInput](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceInput.html#perpage) component:

page - The current page number (default = 1)

perPage - Number of suggestions to show (default = 25)

Comment: Thanks! I'll review ReferenceInput properties from now on.